# One featured question or none? Make up your mind!

Tags: bug, bounty

I noticed something odd in the sidebar just now: an ad for "01" bounties with no total bounty amount. So I went to check it out, and found *this*:

[image: Screenshot of Featured tab]

After hard refreshing, this remains. I checked my ignored tags, and they're not set to hide questions.

Answer (score 2):

For some context: I had a bounty on [Which Dragon Magazine issue did this unusual rat-like race appear in?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78967/which-dragon-magazine-issue-did-this-unusual-rat-like-race-appear-in) that [the revision history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/92454/revisions) says I awarded at `00:46:13Z` ([the "Z" means "UTC+0"](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z)). At the time, it was the last bounty active on the site. You posted this at `02:58:46Z`.

I'd say "caching" but 2 hours is a long time for caching on the *featured* tab.